# How to dynamically reference to another cell in other workbooks?

Tags: excel

i'm trying to create an excel workbook that will automatically collect data from other workbooks in the directory i come up with a code but it does not work correctly

```
="'"&LEFT(CELL("filename",$A$1),FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(CELL("filename",$A$1),"[","~",1))-1)&"["&RIGHT(LEFT(CELL("filename",$A$1),FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(CELL("filename",$A$1),"[","~",1))-2),3)&RIGHT(LEFT(CELL("filename",$A$1),FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(CELL("filename",$A$1),"[","~",1))+16),1)&".xlsx]Final Data'!"&E3
```

if i use this code it will call the value of the `E3` in the current workbook if i use `ADDRESS(3,5)` it will give me the right address but the moment i put `=INDIRECT()` before it, the value of `E3`(in the current workbook) will come up (the other file is open since i'm using indirect). how can i correct this and is there a way to get ell values while the file is closed ?

Comment: It is not possible to call an external workbook with `INDIRECT` function unless the workbook is open. According to [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)

Comment: try `#powerquery` if you are using Excel 2010 Professional Plus or later versions of Excel.